# How to put html element into the label within asp checkbox?

Tags: asp.net

Basically what I need to get rendered is this:

```
<input id="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PageContent$SettingsPage$RFID Info" checked="checked">
<label for="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info">
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>
```

meanwhile System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox gives me only this:

```
<input id="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PageContent$SettingsPage$RFID Info" checked="checked">
<label for="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info">
    RFID Info
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you aren't going to necessarily have much control with regards to how ASP.NET is going to render your CheckBox, you have two options to consider for resolving this.

**Consider Not Using a CheckBox Control**

If it is an option, you might want to consider using a plain `<input>` element decorated with the `runat="server"` attribute (so it can be accessed via the code-behind) instead of a CheckBox Control. This should give you more flexibility with how it is appears as you won't have to worry about the default generated code :

```
<!-- This should allow you to still access RFIDInfo in your code-behind -->
<input id="RFID_Info" runat="server" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**Use Javascript or jQuery to Replace the HTML Content**

Another option, if you wanted to use the CheckBox Control would be to consider performing a client-side replacement via Javascript or jQuery to target the appropriate label and replace the contents :

```
// Pure Javascript approach
document.querySelector('[for$="RFID Info"]').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>'

// jQuery approach
$(function(){
   // Replace the contents of your label with your Font Awesome icon
   $('label[for$="RFID Info"]').html('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Label Replacement</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PageContent$SettingsPage$RFID Info" checked="checked">
  <label for="MainContent_PageContent_SettingsPage_RFID Info">
    RFID Info
  </label>
  <script>
    document.querySelector('[for$="RFID Info"]').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```