# make portions of checkbox text bold

Tags: html, asp.net

How can I make some portions of the checkbox text bold. I have the following checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPart1" runat="server" Text="To obtain a" + <b>"valid"</b> + "Copy you must check the appropriate box below:" + <b>"I am:" + </b>" />
```

I want to make Valid and I am bold in the above text so I want something like this:

[image]

I tried writing the code this way:

To obtain an **valid** Copy you must check the appropriate box below: **I am:**

and this is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682091/how-to-put-html-element-into-the-label-within-asp-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an input type `checkbox` with `label`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPart1" runat="server" Text="" /> <label for="chkPart1">
  To obtain a <b>valid</b> Copy you must check the appropriate box below: <b>I am:</b>
</label>
```

Comment: somehow my checkbox is overlapping my text. I posted the image

Comment: That's may be due to some css already written for input type checkbox